# Import Export Visual Studio errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, settings

I get 2 errors when I import (or export) settings, but unfortunately not very descriptive:

Error 1: Failed to export settings for '#2015' [code 7366]

Error 2: Failed to export settings for '#2001' [code 7366]

I suspect #2001 and #2015 are an ID of some setting.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is what I could find, but this even happens if I export settings after a full settings reset: [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1591136/keep-tabs-option-for-xaml-editor-not-working)

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1591136/keep-tabs-option-for-xaml-editor-not-working